# How to set a field in a row to number of some rows in the same table without concurrency problems in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, isolation

Assume I have an schema like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test2" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "text" CHAR(10),

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE TABLE "test1" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "fkey" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "order" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

ALTER TABLE "test1" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("fkey") REFERENCES "test2"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

for some performance optimizations i want to store in the **"order"** field, number of rows in **"test1"** table referencing same row in **"test2"**. So i try this on inserts:

```sql
insert INTO "test1"
        ("fkey","order")
        select '3', count(*) from "test1" where "fkey"='3';
```

Can this have concurrency problems? (e.g. When two threads insert to **test1** with same **fkey** at the same time can the values of **order** become incorrect? How to solve this issue?

Comment: The question is somewhat confusing to me, but of course the new values will become stale immediately if somebody modifies `test2`. You need a trigger if you want to keep the values synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to account for concurrency issues when multiple inserts are done at the same time.

There are several solutions. Off the top of my head I can see:

- Acquire an exclusive lock in the database. Probably a row in the main table will do.
- Manage a lock or semaphore outside the database.
- Insert the rows, but update the `order` in a deferred way, probably using a queue (most likely a priority queue), or single separate process.
- Use optimistick locking while inserting.

Each one of these have some drawbacks, so it'll depend on the specific requirements you have.

I would guess that you don't want to update *all siblings* each time you insert a new child; that could be overkill in terms of performance. If this sounds reasonable, maybe you can use a priority queue, run a process every 10 minutes (or so), group all children of the same parent and update them at once.

Comment: I used your third idea, in my case updating with createdAt field i think we can omit deference and updated after my inserts.